Unable to Find Issue With New Network Setup
can someone find or guess whats wrong?
Equipment:

ISP CPE - Huawei HG8145V5
Switch in Office - TP Link TL-SG108E
Switch in Bedroom - TP-Link TL-SG105E
Wifi Router in Bedroom - TP Link Archer C20 (AC750)

Original Setup
I had a setup my home network like so:

ISP provided CPE (modem, router and wifi access point) served wifi.
A Cat5 cable wired through the wall connected the CPE router to a switch (TL-SG108E) in my office.
Another Cat5 cable wired through the wall connected the CPE router to wifi router in bedroom.

This worked fine until, I decided to make some improvements.
New Setup
In the new setup, I have a Raspberry Pi4 configured with USB3->Ethernet adapter.

ethernet adapter of Pi4 plugs into the CPE ethernet port.
inbuilt ethernet of Pi4 goes into a TP-Link switch TL-SG105E.
Office switch connects to the TL-SG105E over Cat5 cable.
Bedroom wifi router connects to TL-SG105E over Cat5 cable.

Observations

My original connections in office are all working fine. However, the
other router was having issues with internet.
The cat5 cable connecting wifi router C20 and TL-SG105E switch has
its orange light flash for a second or so and turn off for two
seconds. And this repeats.
Connecting the cable to any other port of TL-SG105E has no change
in behavior.
Connecting the cable directly to the CPE ethernet port instead of
TL-SG105E is working fine.
Connecting the cable directly to Pi4's ethernet port instead of TL-SG105E also works fine. Connecting the cable to TL-SG105E on one end and TL-SG108E on another also works fine.

It appears that the cable and TL-SG105E are working as expected. But for some reason the combination of the cable, C20 wifi router and TL-SG105E is not working.
Based on your experience, what is preventing the cat5 cable to connect the TL-SG105E and my old wifi router?
Update 30Jun 2024:
From the TL-SG105E switch management page, I see that the link status keeps changing between "Link Down" and "100Full". Also, the "TxGoodPkt" keeps on increasing, and "RxGoodPkt", "TxBadPkt" and "RxBadPkt" are all zero (0) for the port where ethernet is connected.
On switch's "Cable Test" page the port reports "Cross Cable". However, I believe cross cable should still work. Because I have a working connection between my TL-SG108E and network printer via a cross cable.

Does it report which pairs (and which pins) are crossed? The Archer is a 10M/100M-only device, so I wouldn't be surprised to see it handle weird cables differently than 1G devices do.

hey @grawity_u1686, I guess it might be that. However, I got an old cisco Linksys WRT160Nv3 lying around. It also has a 10/100 ethernet. However, I was surprised to see the Linksys connect and the port on TL-SG105E was solid orange and flickering during data transmission!
I am getting a solid 25-30mbps from Linksys on my android smartphone.
I figure some esoteric problem with combination of this particular cable, TL-SG105E and TL Archer C20 switch.

I had an old Cisco Linksys WRT160Nv3 lying around. Linksys is working fine when I replaced Archer C20 with it
As commented in reply to @grawity_u1686, the port on TL-SG105E is OK and speed from the Linksys wifi router is also good enough at 25-30mbps.
At the end of this, I believe there is weird incompatibility with given combination of cable, switch and wifi router.
One other thing I noticed, not sure how relevant it is though, the subnet of Linksys is 10.74.x.x while the one on my Pi is 192.168.x.x.
Would a subnet of 192.168.y.x on Archer C20 have issues with the switch because of Pi's 192.168.x.x?
Something for me to try some other day!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
